# Is there any nice way to compute transfer homomorphism in a $p$-group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Set $V$ be a pretransfer map from $G$ to $H$.

That is, $$V(g)=\prod_{t\in T} tg(t.g)^{-1}=\prod_{t\in T_0}tg^n_tt^{-1} $$

Can we say that the image $V(G)$ is contained in a (special subgroup) of $H$? Possible under some assumption on the structure of $H$. For example if $H$ is a regular $p$-group what can we say about the  image $V(G)$?